# Open shared drive document in Word from browser

Tags: browser, ms-word, uri, share, drive

I have a share drive with lot of word documents, and i made a simple webpage which listing them. I want to open them with directly in Word. I found an URI scheme (`ms-word:ofe|u|<document path>`) but that not able to open from share drive, just from local drives.

I tried to use this `ms-word:ofv|u|//<share drive>/test.docx` but just open a blank Word. Without the double slash, word trying to open from the C drive.

Do you guys have any idea how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the http or https schema keyword. The final URI should be something like

```
ms-word:ofe|u|https://sharepoint.com/shared/YOUR_WORD_DOCUMENT.docx
```